# Relation between Sherwood and Peclet numbers

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow, physical-chemistry, convection

What's the relation between [Sherwood number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherwood_number) and [Peclet number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%A9clet_number) for mass transfer in a rectangular channel with fully developed laminar flow?

Comment: The Wikipedia links in the post indicate one is convective while the other is advective. Does that help?